# Bash how to check if a string is a number(can be negative)

Tags: bash

I want to check if a certain string is a number, I tried this way:

```
if ${string} == *[!0-9]*
else echo its a number
```

but when I have a negative number, it says it's not a number, and i want it to work for negative numbers too.

Comment: No, it doesnt work for negative numbers

Comment: In that question you can find some answers that take into account negative numbers.

Comment: @Sefi, the accepted answer there had a solution for negative numbers in its comments; I've edited it into the answer proper.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot, but when I have a number like this "---7" it says it is not a number instead of reading it as -7

Comment: @Sefi, `---7` *isn't* a number; the logic is correct. If you wanted zero-or-more `-` signs, though, you'd use `-*` instead of `-?`. By the way, the comments in the other answer discuss this too. :)

Comment: @Sefi, ...or rather, `---7` is only as much a number as `1+2` is a number; it's a unary operation being applied to the number `-7` twice, flipping it each time, just as `1+2` is a binary operation being applied to two numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this script

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$1

if [[ "$string" =~ ^(-)?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo 'Number'
else
  echo 'Not number'
fi
```

This works only for integers.

If you want to match and decimal number then use this test

```
"$string" =~ ^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: +1 for what i think you paste here queckly

Comment: Thanks alot, but when I have number like this "---7" it says it is not a number.

Comment: @Sefi you should have only one minus signe before number. If you want more than one minus signe then replace (-)? with (-)*

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!

Comment: In the decimal form you should replace `*` with `?`, otherwise you'll also match input such as `1.2.3`. (As an aside: I assume you used `(-)?` rather than just `-?` for readability.)

Comment: @mklement0 my mistake Thannk you